# Naming convention for function implemented in assembly but used in C?

Tags: c, assembly, naming-conventions

When a project has both C and assembly, and their naming conventions clash, is it better to rename function is assembly, or accept the clash in C?

In assembly file memory.s (I didn't write: it's imported, and uses a CamelCase naming convention that doesn't match the C coding convention):

```
global _WriteFlash
```

In the memory.h file:

```
extern int  WriteFlash(int flashAddress, int flashData);
```

In a C file using it:

```
WriteFlash(flash_address, flash_data);
```

But, the naming convention for C would make that:

```
write_flash(flash_address, flash_data);
```

Should I force the C naming convention onto the assembly file, or accept the unconventional function name in my C code?

That is:

1) Do I change the function name in assembly file to lower case and underscores?

2) Or do I live with the CamelCase function name in C?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you simply saying that you are using a pre-written function that doesn't adhere to your project's coding conventions?

Comment: there does not exist a general naming convention; it depends on the used compiler/linker.

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth: yes

Comment: Use what's given when it is given and can't be changed.  There's no point in fighting the external source.  It may not match your main coding standard — that's sad, but not a tragedy.  If you're really worried, have the 'memory.h' header (or a wrapper for it) define `static inline int write_flash(void *flash_address, uint8_t flash_data) { return WriteFlash(flash_address, flash_data); }` (parameter types assumed — fix to match what you really have).  Then write your code using your preferred naming convention.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler - Thanks. That's a good answer. If you wish, re-enter it as an Answer and I'll mark it as the solution.